# Scrolling problem

Tags: javascript

Here I have a challenge.
When I am logged in in my Drupal site: NO PROBLEM WITH SCROLLING THE PAGES
When I am lopgged out: I can't scrolll the page as normal.
This problem **only occurs with Google Chrome**, other pages is no problem.
When I clear all cache, log out, then the first time I can scroll the page without problems. Visit the site again, the scrolling problem is there again.

Any suggestions?

The website: www.vankesselnatuursteen.nl

*Ps. With Chrome I have no problem at all at other Drupal sites*

Further information. I moved the site to another domain on my server. There where some problems and a changed some chmod rights of some folders and files.

THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR HELPING

Answer (score 1):

There is an error on the page if you scroll before the page is fully loaded:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined

line 95 of smoothscroll.js.

**update**
Looks like a bug to me try changing:

```
function ssc_wheel(e) {
    if (!ssc_initdone) {
      init();
    }
```

to:

```
function ssc_wheel(e) {
    if (!ssc_initdone) {
      ssc_init();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that...Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I replaced the smoothscroll.js with the origonal of the theme. No results, some other site of the same theme are scrolling well. I must have messed up something with transferring to other domain...but what is it?

Comment: smoothscroll is calling the init function before the init function is loaded. Make sure whatever contains the init function is loaded before smoothscroll, though I could not find an init function. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks so far...The changed code you suggest is the same is the original above?

Comment: ? no, changed code calls ssc_init() instead of init()

Comment: Sorry, you are right, thanks, I am gonna try this!! I keep you informed

Comment: I tried, after logging out, visited the site again, no scrolling again...The strange thing is...when I am logged in, NO PROBLEM...logged out...PROBLEM

Comment: ? It seems fixed to me. No more error and scrolling working fine.

Comment: Strange...Does it function with Google chrome? When I am logged in or logged out, the same problem is there...

Comment: Strange...Does it function with Google chrome? When I am logged in or logged out, the same problem is there...Only whe I point at the right scrollbar, it is functioning. I disabled de smooth scroll funtion (by the way)...Other browsers is scrolling no problem...

Comment: For now I put back the original code. I appreciate your help very much so far!